# Ошибка в получение тега

Tags: javascript

Я получил тег p по id в js файле, но когда перезагрузил страницу мне написали что файл не найден,а в поисковой строке на конце было написано [object%20HTMLParagraphElement].Как это исправить?

Comment: "мне написали" - кто написали?

Comment: _Как это исправить?_ - не перезагружай страницу

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена, просто использовал эту конструкцию

```
document.getElementsByClassName("weather-data-cluster__location")[0].innerHTML
```

Вместо того чтобы записать в переменную